# Talend: Get most common value in a column

Tags: database, talend

I have a table with a couple hundred rows. I want to know the most common value of the data in one of the columns. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you do it in your sql query with something like this :

```
select top 1 column, count(*) cnt  
from table  
group by column  
order by count(*) desc
```

This syntax has to be adapted to your rdbms. For instance, in Oracle it would be something like this :

```
select column from (  
  select column, count(*)  
  from table  
  group by column  
  order by count(*) desc  
) where rownum = 1
```

If you want to do it in Talend you can use :

```
Input -- tAggregateRow -- tSortRow -- tSampleRow -- Output
```

In tAggregateRow you use a count function to count the frequency of values in your column, then you sort them by descending order in tSortRow, then you get the first line with tSampleRow (just put "1")